# Mi sitio web no respeta el formato de hora

Tags: c#, asp.net

Hola tengo un reporte de asistencia montado en iis en un servidor windows server 2012 R2 Standard, en la programación de mi reporte pongo el formato de hora que necesito, que es AM-PM
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

pero en mi reporte me sale así, no especifica si es pm o am

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

ya cheque la configuración de mi servidor y esta bien

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

también verifiqué desde el registro

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Alguna idea? :/ ayudaaaaaa

el reporte esta programado en c#, pasa algo raro, cuando cambio el formato a H:mm si funciona de 24hrs pero no funciona con el de 12 hrs

Comment: Que reporteador usas reportviewer

Comment: Hola @Japv uso Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms

Comment: ¿Estás seguro que tt es aceptado por el código? No tiene por qué la misma String que Windows. Por ejemplo en PHP para indicar el AM o PM se usa "A"

Comment: Hola @YORS sí es aceptado por el código. Ese reporte lo hice en una compu con windows 10 y todo funciona bien, pero al momento de pasarlo al windows server es que me causa ese detalle, solo es ese formato que no me funciona ya que probé con el formato de 24hrs que es H:mm y ese sí funciona

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo solucioné agregando new System.Globalization.CultureInfo ("en-US") en mi archivo de reporte

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Felicidades tienes mi voto

Comment: Hola @Javp disculpa ya te puse el voto y muchas gracias

Answer (score 2):

Bien parece que en ReportViewer la cosa no es tan obvia,

Da clic derecho sobre el **TexBox** de la hora en el ReportViewer y da clic en expresion, ahí pega este codigo:

```
=Switch(Now.Hour > 12, Now.ToString("hh:mm") + " PM", 
    Now.Hour < 12, Now.ToString("hh:mm") + " AM",
    Now.Hour = 12, Now.ToString("hh:mm") + " M")
```

Digamos que este es el lenguaje propio del ReportViewer, aquí lo que se hace es un **switch** donde en caso de que la hora del tiempo(el tiempo tiene horas, minutos, segundos) sea mayor a **12** escribimos el tiempo concatenado con pm, si es menor que **12** el tiempo concatenado con AM y si es **12** el tiempo concatenado con M.

Si la fecha y/o hora viene de la base de datos entonces prueba esto:

```
=Switch(Hour(Fields!FechaNacimiento.Value) > 12 And    Minute(Fields!FechaNacimiento.Value) < 10,  (Hour(Fields!FechaNacimiento.Value) - 12) & ":0" &  Minute(Fields!FechaNacimiento.Value) & " PM",
    Hour(Fields!FechaNacimiento.Value) > 12 And  Minute(Fields!FechaNacimiento.Value) > 9, (Hour(Fields!FechaNacimiento.Value)  - 12) & ":" & Minute(Fields!FechaNacimiento.Value) & " PM",
    Hour(Fields!FechaNacimiento.Value) = 0 And  Minute(Fields!FechaNacimiento.Value) = 0,  "12:00 AM",
    Hour(Fields!FechaNacimiento.Value) = 0 And  Minute(Fields!FechaNacimiento.Value) < 10, "12:0" &  Minute(Fields!FechaNacimiento.Value) & " AM",
    Hour(Fields!FechaNacimiento.Value) = 0 And Minute(Fields!FechaNacimiento.Value) > 9, "12:" & Minute(Fields!FechaNacimiento.Value) & " AM",
    Hour(Fields!FechaNacimiento.Value) < 12 And Minute(Fields!FechaNacimiento.Value) < 10, Hour(Fields!FechaNacimiento.Value) & ":0" & Minute(Fields!FechaNacimiento.Value) & " AM",
    Hour(Fields!FechaNacimiento.Value) < 12 And Minute(Fields!FechaNacimiento.Value) > 9, Hour(Fields!FechaNacimiento.Value) & ":" & Minute(Fields!FechaNacimiento.Value) & " AM",
    Hour(Fields!FechaNacimiento.Value) = 12 And Minute(Fields!FechaNacimiento.Value) = 0,  "12:00 M",
    Hour(Fields!FechaNacimiento.Value) = 12 And Minute(Fields!FechaNacimiento.Value) < 10, "12:0" & Minute(Fields!FechaNacimiento.Value) & " PM",
    Hour(Fields!FechaNacimiento.Value) = 12 And Minute(Fields!FechaNacimiento.Value) > 9, "12:" & Minute(Fields!FechaNacimiento.Value) & " PM")
```

Aquí se hace un **switch** y se van concatenando las horas con los minutos desde el campo de la base de datos, si es mayor que **12** se pone PM, menor AM, igual M, aquí la concatenación se hace con el **operador &**. Con **Hour** obtengo la hora del campo y con **Minute** los minutos del campo.

Comment: Hola @Japv si me ha funcionado, pero tengo una duda si pongo *Now.Hour* obtengo la hora actual pero yo necesito una hora que viene desde la base de datos, como puse en la primera imagen actualmente tiene =CDate(Fields!FixedExit.Value).ToString("hh:mm tt") intenté poner el Fields!FixedExit.Value en lugar de Now.Hour pero me marca error :(

Comment: @Ana ya, revisa, si te ha servido la respuesta por favor marcala como aceptada y/o da un voto, cualquier cosa me avisas, yo he probado con varias horas y funciona